# Yarn causes MSB3552 Resource file "**/*.resx" cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-core, hadoop-yarn

We are experiencing a strange issue, after having run `yarn start` or `yarn build` on our ClientApp (ReactJS).

We have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project with a SPA in React running on top of it. When we run yarn start, it causes dotnet project to break, it causes the errors:

> MSB3552   Resource file "**/*.resx" cannot be found

> MSB4018   The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.

And in Visual Studio (2019) the project then looks like this:

[image: Visual studio error]

Which causes the build to fail. I unable to figure out file has changed (git doesn't detect changes) and is causing this.

I noticed that dotnet build still works when running that from command line.

I found similar issues, where people report this when using macOs and the project file contains Windows paths. I have checked the project and solution file, but couldn't find and absolute paths like that.
Tested on multiple machines (all Windows 10 + Visual Studio 2019) and all give the same problem. The React App is also being edited on MacOs, but we couldn't identity any path related issues to that.

Anybody an idea what might causing this?

**Update:**
I noticed when I delete the node_modules folder from the ClientApp folder, it works in Visual Studio again. However when running yarn again, the problem reoccurs.

Comment: I am having the same issue, what version of yarn are you running? Did you install your yarn globally or via NPM?

Comment: I have yarn installed globally. Running version 1.21.1 at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Fixed the issue by excluding the ClientApp folder in the project.

Related issue: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8659

Edit the cs project file and add the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>node_modules/**;$(DefaultItemExcludes)</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="ClientApp\**" />
    <Content Remove="ClientApp\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="ClientApp\**" />
    <None Remove="ClientApp\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when our .NET app hosted SPA (deps installed by any package manager such as npm, pnpm, yarn). The VS was trying to build our solution, but the problem is `node_modules` and all its installed content that VS has issues resolving their file system paths. So, either exclude it for .NET solution/project for a build or delete `node_modules` to build the back-end solution.